# How to apply a filter to webcam in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7

How can I apply a sepia or black and white filter to my webcam using OpenCV and Python?

I have this code to display my webcam:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

c = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):
    _,f = c.read()    
    cv2.imshow('e2',  f   )

    if cv2.waitKey(5)==27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the link, [making sepia with python-opencv](http://www.vision.ime.usp.br/~rafaellg/2012/06/23/making-sepia-images-with-python-opencv/). Basically, you need to construct the sepia matrix and apply it on each pixel.

**Dependencies**: `numpy`